# Constant variance assumption in regression model

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, assumptions

My question is how do we check the constant variance assumption in a **regression model**?

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? If not, what else do you need to know? If yes, please check the accept button below the voting arrows.

Answer (score 6):

Another name for contant variance assumption is **homoskedasticity**, and its opposite is [**heteroskedasticity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroscedasticity). To find heteroskedasticity, you can both visually look at the relationship between the fitted values (predicted `y`) and the residuals  and perform the Breusch-Pagan test. In R:

```
# generate a heteroskedastic independent variable x
set.seed(0)
n <- 1000
x <- rgamma(n, shape=6, scale=1/2)
e <- rnorm(length(x), sd=abs(sin(x)))
# which determines the dependent variable y
y <- x + e
# look at the relationship
plot(y ~ x)
```

[image: relationship between x and y]

By looking at the scatterplot it already becomes apparent that `y` doesn't have a constant variance.

You can then plot the linear model itself to get a plot of the relationship between the fitted values (predicted y) and the residuals:

```
# fit a linear model
lm1 <- lm(y ~ x)
# look at the residuals
plot(lm1)
# press enter once
```

[image: relationship between fitted values and residuals]

Again, it becomes pretty clear that the variance of the residuals isn't constant.

To get a quantitative measure of heteroskedasticity, perform the Breusch-Pagan test (requires the `lmtest`-Package):

```
# load library
library(lmtest)
# perform test
bptest(lm1)
```

This gives:

```
    studentized Breusch-Pagan test

data:  lm1 
BP = 12.2634, df = 1, p-value = 0.0004619
```

A high BP-Value with a significant p-value means that the Null-Hypothesis of fit and residuals being uncorrelated can be rejected, thus you have heteroskedasticity in your data (in this case).